# sorting of words in a sentence

Tags: java, sorting

How can I seperate words in a sentence and I want it by using for or while statements and with using which methods, I don't know exactly. For example, our string is `"one two three four"`. I want it sorted as an output like below;

```
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: By "sorting" do you mean "replace spaces by linebreaks"?

Comment: you want to take a string and display it as an unordered list in alphabetical order?

Comment: I don't want it in an alphabetical order, just seperate each word from the string

Comment: That's not sorting, that's tokenizing.

Comment: @Brian: I'm curious, how's an "unordered list in alphabetical order" possible?

Comment: Where are talking about an split? or we want to do anything more?

Comment: I asked it because nobody could have answered my first question, I've just wanted to examine that: is anybody in stackoverflow that able to give me an idea about that easy query

Comment: @Mac  anything in <ul> and <li> tags can be sorted in whatever order you like via javascript.   unordered list in html terms is referring to the styling not the actual sorting.

Comment: @Brian: very true, I hadn't considered the term "unordered" in that manner, mostly because the question has nothing to do with HTML (or markup of any kind really)...

Answer (score 3):

```
String newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(" ", "\n");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: For extra robustness, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/247059/436282) for tips on newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a point to start:

```
String text = "one two three four";
String[] words = text.split(" ");
// Now implement any sorting algorithm on the array "words"
```