# How to append a newline to StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object,

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.append(someChar);
```

Now I want to append a newline character to the `StringBuilder`. How can I do it?

```
result.append("/n");
```

Does not work. So, I was thinking about writing a newline using Unicode. Will this help? If so, how can I add one?

Comment: I thought it is `"\n"`, or [`System.getProperty("line.separator")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247059/is-there-a-newline-constant-defined-in-java-like-environment-newline-in-c).

Comment: A [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is not necessarily a LINE FEED (LF) (Ascii/Unicode 10) character. As the [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14534798/642706) points out, in Java you can get either one (LINE FEED or a platform-specific newline).

Answer (score 607, accepted):

It should be

```
r.append("\n");
```

But I recommend you to do as below,

```
r.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` gives you system-dependent newline in java. Also from Java 7 there's a method that returns the value directly: [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29)

Comment: +1 for the System.lineSeparator shortcut. The bigger question is why there isn't a `StringBuilder#appendLine()` method.

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` documentation mentions "Returns the system-dependent line separator string.". This is not platform independant. Use this code if you need to write a string that will be used by the underlying operating system, otherwise use `'\n'`.

Comment: @tuscland - Why not just use System.lineSeparator() all the time? Why is '\n' a better option as default?

Comment: No, `System.lineSeparator()` should be used when you deal with non-portable resources (that is, resources specific to the underlying operating system). It has a different value wether you are running Java on Windows (\r\n) or Unix (\n). If you use `System.lineSeparator()` all the time, you will therefore produce non portable files.

Comment: Unbelievable there's not already an `appendLine` overload on `StringBuilder`.

Comment: System.getProperty("line.separator") works in sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, digipaz.toString());

Comment: Any Android devs using Kotlin that may have stumbled here, this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/57705139/2445763

Comment: In Kotlin I still just add "\n" to my string when I need it...

Answer (score 30):

Another option is to use Apache Commons StrBuilder, which has the functionality that's lacking in StringBuilder.

[StrBuilder.appendLn()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrBuilder.html#appendln(org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrBuilder))

As of version 3.6 StrBuilder has been deprecated in favour of [TextStringBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/TextStringBuilder.html) which has the same functionality

Comment: ... and since Java 8 there's [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), which "_is used to construct a sequence of characters separated by a delimiter and optionally starting with a supplied prefix and ending with a supplied suffix._" Using "\n" as delimiter would result in new lines (except for the last one). Internally, it uses a StringBuilder. The same approach could be realized using the Google Guava Joiner, I assume.

Comment: ... and now this is `deprecated`. Please use `org.apache.commons.text.TextStringBuilder`.

Comment: `TextStringBuilder` is not in `commons-lang3`, it is in `commons-text` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/

Answer (score 20):

Escape should be done with `\`, not `/`.

So `r.append('\n');` or `r.append("\n");` will work (`StringBuilder` has overloaded methods for `char` and `String` type).

Answer (score 7):

I create original class that similar to StringBuidler and can append line by calling method appendLine(String str).

```
public class StringBuilderPlus {

    private StringBuilder sb;

    public StringBuilderPlus(){
         sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void append(String str)
    {
        sb.append(str != null ? str : "");
    }

    public void appendLine(String str)
    {
        sb.append(str != null ? str : "").append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
StringBuilderPlus sb = new StringBuilderPlus();
sb.appendLine("aaaaa");
sb.appendLine("bbbbb");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Console:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the line separator character in `String.format` (See `java.util.Formatter`), which is also platform agnostic.

i.e.:

```
result.append(String.format("%n", ""));
```

If you need to add more line spaces, just use:

```
result.append(String.format("%n%n", ""));
```

You can also use `StringFormat` to format your entire string, with a newline(s) at the end.

```
result.append(String.format("%10s%n%n", "This is my string."));
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `line.seperator` for appending new line in

Answer (score 3):

In addition to K.S's response of creating a StringBuilderPlus class and utilising ther  adapter pattern to extend a final class, if you make use of generics and return the StringBuilderPlus object in the new append and appendLine methods, you can make use of the StringBuilders many append methods for all different types, while regaining the ability to string string multiple append commands together, as shown below

```
public class StringBuilderPlus {

    private final StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public StringBuilderPlus() {
        this.stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public <T> StringBuilderPlus append(T t) {
        stringBuilder.append(t);
        return this;
    }

    public <T> StringBuilderPlus appendLine(T t) {
        stringBuilder.append(t).append(System.lineSeparator());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public StringBuilder getStringBuilder() {
        return stringBuilder;
    }
}
```

you can then use this exactly like the original StringBuilder class:

```
StringBuilderPlus stringBuilder = new StringBuilderPlus();
stringBuilder.appendLine("test")
    .appendLine('c')
    .appendLine(1)
    .appendLine(1.2)
    .appendLine(1L);

stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: there is quite a few conversion problems here.