# How to convert a String Array to a String for my toString method

Tags: java, arrays, string, tostring

This is my `toString` method.

```
public String toString() {
   Life game = new Life(grid);
   String word;
       for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
               System.out.print("[" + grid[row][col] + "]");  
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   word = "";
   return word;
}
```

I am trying to get the `("[" + grid[row][col] + "]")`; into my `String` word. This is to create a game of life grid and I can't figure out how to put the array into a string representation.

Some sample of what it should look like if all the cells were dead. `

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

When I try word = word + "[" + grid[row][col] + "]"; i get...

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]...
```

All in a straight line.

Comment: give a sample input and desired output

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html.

Comment: Can you add how did you declare your grid array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with two issues here:

- **Collecting the output into a `String`** - this can be done with [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class, and
- **Adding a newline to the output string** - this is explained in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534798/335858)

The end result should look as follows:

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
for (int row = 0 ; row < grid.length ; row++) {
    for (int col = 0 ; col < grid[row].length ; col++) {
        res.append('[');
        res.append(grid[row][col]);
        res.append(']');
    }
    // Do not append the trailing newline
    if (row != grid.length-1) {
        res.append(newline);
    }
}
return res.toString();
```

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Although it does not appear to matter in OP's case because his array is rectangular, using `row` as an index is safer in case someone decides to copy-paste this code, and use it for a jagged array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Java 8's `StringJoiner`:

```
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner iJoiner = new StringJoiner(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    for (int i = 0 ; i < grid.length ; i++) {
        StringJoiner jJoiner = new StringJoiner("][", "[", "]");
        for (int j = 0 ; j < grid[i].length ; j++) {
            jJoiner.add("" + grid[i][j]);
        }
        iJoiner.add(jJoiner.toString());
    }
    return iJoiner.toString();
}
```

`StringJoiner` puts delimiters between (but not before or after) elements, and optionally adds a prefix or suffix.

It's worth looking at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/StringJoiner.java), for the elegant way it achieves this.

You could also do this in a Stream-oriented manner using `Collectors.joining()` -- which is a simple `Collector` implemented around `StringJoiner`:

```
 return Arrays.stream(grid)
     .map(row ->
         Arrays.stream(row)
             .mapToObj( x -> ""+x )
             .collect(Collectors.joining("][", "[", "]"))
     .collect(Collectors.joining(lineSeparator));
```

- Makes a `Stream<int[]>` from the input `int[][]`
- Using `map()` to process each `int[]`:

  - Make the `int[]` into an `IntStream`
  - `mapToObj` the `IntStream` into a `Stream<String>` with an item for each cell of the row
  - Collect the `Stream<String>` into a formatted row String `"[1][2][3]"`
  - `map()` therefore returns a `Stream<String>`
- Collect the `Stream<String>` into one newline-separated String