# System.lineSeparator() does not work in Linux environment

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Java 8 and Spring API to  compose the mail body as below.

```
        StringBuilder emailTemplateForNewPassword = new StringBuilder();
        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("Dear User,");

        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append(System.lineSeparator());
        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append(System.lineSeparator());

        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("Sample Mail.");

        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append(System.lineSeparator());
        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append(System.lineSeparator());

        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("Yours Faityfully,");
        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append(System.lineSeparator());
        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("ABC.Com");
        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append(System.lineSeparator());
        emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("0094778999658");
```

> **Expected result:**
>
> Dear User,
>
> Sample Mail.
>
> Yours Faithfully,
>  ABC.Com
>  0094778999658
>
> **Actual Result:**
>
> Dear User,
>
> Sample Mail.
>
> Yours Faithfully, ABC.Com 0094778999658

I am not sure why the last 3 lines come on same line even that I used `System.lineSeparator()`.

I have already tried `"\r\n"` but no luck.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong ?

I know that there are other questions related to this but none of them imsolve my problem. Please do not  downcast this question until I find the answer.

Comment: Perhaps because whatever you are giving this string to actually requires `\r\n`?

Comment: I use System.lineSeparator(). It should handle this right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append a newline to StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534767/how-to-append-a-newline-to-stringbuilder)

Comment: @Java-Seekar if the API you are using expects `\r\n`, you should use `\r\n`: `System.lineSeparator()` depends upon the JVM's configuration.

Comment: What client are using to view the email?

Comment: windows outlook

Answer (score 5):

[RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) describes the standard for email.

Per [Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1):

> Messages are divided into lines of characters.  A line is a series of
> characters that is **delimited with the two characters carriage-return
> and line-feed**; that is, the carriage return (CR) character (ASCII
> value 13) followed immediately by the line feed (LF) character (ASCII
> value 10).  (The carriage return/line feed pair is usually written in
> this document as "CRLF".)

You need to use `\r\n` explicitly to separate your lines.

You can't rely upon `System.lineSeparator()`, because this is dependent upon JVM config; by default, that config will use just `\n` on Linux.

Comment: emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("Yours Faityfully,");
  emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("\r\n");
  emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("ABC.Com");
  emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("\r\n");
  emailTemplateForNewPassword.append("0094778999658");

Comment: Still I get the same issue

Comment: Some one downcast the question without solving the issue. Then what is the purpose of having forum like this? Really disappointed. I tried this whole day today but still no luck.

Comment: @Java-Seekar actually, two people have (neither of whom are me). I'd imagine because you haven't provided enough information to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have fixed this issue by using MimeMessage and set the content type as "text/html". I have separated the lines using <br>. The person who down voted this question couldn't provide the correct answer. Please don't de motivate us by down voting.