# How to append a new line to StringBuilder in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, stringbuilder

In Java, Following code is one way to achieve.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.append(someChar);
result.append("\n");
```

Idiomatic way of doing it in kotlin?

Comment: Just remove "new"...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kotlin 1.3 provides [Extension Function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/appendln.html) to ease the task.

Usage:

```
val strBuilder = StringBuilder()
strBuilder.appendln("some text")
```

In Kotlin 1.4 `appendln()` is deprecated and [appendLine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/append-line.html) is introduced.

Usage:

```
val strBuilder = StringBuilder()
strBuilder.appendLine("some text")
```

Comment: In Kotlin 1.4 appendln() is deprecated and  has been replaced by appendLine().

Comment: I don't like extension functions whose name is longer then the string they replace.