# Java split string by newline regex issue with question mark

Tags: java, regex, string, split, newline

I've written a Java class which must pull elements out of a string containing newlines. As a first step the code must split the input string by newline and place the results into an array. This is all working fine except in one specific case. I'm using the following code to perform the split:

```
String lines[] = inputText.split("[\\r?\\n\\r]+");
```

The issue I'm having is with the following line:

```
##INFO=<ID=DS,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description=""removed?"">"
```

It results in two lines:

```
##INFO=<ID=DS,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description=""removed
"">"
```

It is splitting on the question mark. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is happening? Inside a regex doesn't a '?' indicate 0 or 1 occurrence? Is this not an acceptable way to split by newline?

Comment: does `split('\\n')` not work?

Comment: ? does mean 0 or 1 but not inside a [] group, which then means a literal question mark, hence your strange result

Comment: It would yes, but I also have to be able to handle Windows style newlines. I thought I was being safe writing the regex like this. But possibly not!

Comment: @BenShirley you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247059/is-there-a-newline-constant-defined-in-java-like-environment-newline-in-c to make it platform independant maybe?

Comment: Isn't `[\n\r]+` just enough ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. I'll try removing the [] group

@Karthik T thanks for the link. An issue is that the string is coming from a file which could have been created on a system other than the computer performing the split.

Comment: You should split on `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n`. So change your split to: `inputText.split("\r|\r?\n");`

Comment: @Rohit Jain Thank you very much. Your suggested split seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: @Adam Good explanation. I understand what was happening now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a character class(`[]`), which means any of the characters inside the brackets, so in your case `[\\r?\\n\\r]+`, it means *any of `\\r`, `\\n`, `?`, `\\r`, one or more times (+)*.

The real portable regex for a newline, defined by [Unicode UTS #18: Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18), is:

```
\R => (?:(?>\u000D\u000A)|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])
```

as explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4307261/371250) by Tom Christiansen of Perl fame. Accounting for Java's double escaping (string then regex):

```
(?:(?>\\u000D\\u000A)|[\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, simply say \n\r OR \n.

```
String manyLines = "line1\nline2\n\rline3?\nline4";
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(manyLines.split("\\n\\r|\\n")));
```

Output

```
[line1, line2, line3?, line4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question mark inside square brackets is *literally* a question mark. Replace square brackets with round ones(the former is limited to ONE character for each alternation):

```
String lines[] = inputText.split("(\\r?\\n|\\r)+");
```

Lines will be split at "\r\n", "\n" and "\r", but that's effectively the same as:

```
String lines[] = inputText.split("(\\n|\\r)+");
```

So we can back to square brackets:

```
String lines[] = inputText.split("[\\n\\r]+");
```

If what you actually need is a constant newline depending on OS:

```
String lines[] = inputText.split("(" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + ")+");
```