# Writing new line notepad

Tags: java, notepad

Simply trying to move to a new line after printing each element inside of notepad. Some searching has yielded uses of \r\n, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
for(String element : misspelledWords)
                {
                    writer.write(element + "\n");
                }
```

Comment: If you are using BufferedWriter then there is a method newLine() which will insert a new line refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()

Can you please mention whcih writer class you are using

Comment: The expected output would be: word (new line) word2 (newline) word3

Comment: The current output is:wordword2word3

Comment: Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead, because it is compile time OS independent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Newline constant defined in Java like Environment.Newline in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247059/is-there-a-newline-constant-defined-in-java-like-environment-newline-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"));       
    for (String element : misspelledWords) {
        writer.write(element);
        writer.newLine();
    }
```

Adding line separator at the end (like "\n") should work on most OS,but to be on safer side 
you should use **System.getProperty("line.separator")**

Answer (score 0):

Open your file in append mode like this
 `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)` when you want to make an object of class `FileWrite`

in constructor.

```
 File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Izak\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\addNewLinetoTxtFile\\src\\addnewlinetotxtfile\\a.txt");
    try (Writer newLine = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));) {
       newLine.write("New Line!");
       newLine.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Note:

> "**line.separator**" is a Sequence used by operating system to separate lines
>   in text files

source:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html