# Void is not allowed here (GUI Netbeans)

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am trying to use the inheritance concept where I inherit my data from the super class using GUI in Netbeans. I want the button in the form to display the information i got from the super class. However,i am getting the 'Void cannot be allowed' error. Can you help me solve this?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         House myHouse = new House(8);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,myHouse.displayHouseDetails());
    }
```

UPDATE

```
public class Building {

protected String size;
protected double price;

public Building(String size,double price)
{  this.size = size;
  this.price = price;
 }

}

public class House extends Building{
private int houseNo;

  public House(int houseNo)
  {  super("100 X 90",100000);
     this.houseNo = houseNo;
  }
public void displayHouseDetails(){  

     System.out.println("House no:"+houseNo);
     System.out.println("Size:"+size);
     System.out.println("Price:"+price);   
     }
```

btw, may I know how can i make my button to display the data that inherit from super class?

Comment: You did not provide us where exactly it gave the error and slo we have no clue as to what the definition of `House` is.

Comment: myHouse.displayHouseDetails() is this void?

Comment: @Neijwiert i have updated my code

Comment: @HRgiger  i have updated my code

Answer (score 1):

`public void displayHouseDetails()` returns `void` and may not be used as an argument in another function.

It should be:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     House myHouse = new House(8);
     myHouse.displayHouseDetails();
}
```

Or make a concatenated string in the function and return that.

> btw, may I know how can i make my button to display the data that inherit from super class?

Change `displayHouseDetails` to:

```
public String displayHouseDetails(){  
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("House no:");
    builder.append(houseNo).append(System.lineSeparator());
    builder.append("Size:").append(size).append(System.lineSeparator());
    builder.append("Price:").append(price).append(System.lineSeparator());

    return builder.toString();
 }
```

Comment: What i meant by that is that I;m trying to build a program with GUI where when i click the button, it will display all the information that i get from Building class

Comment: upvote for using strinbuilder, also small note:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247059/is-there-a-newline-constant-defined-in-java-like-environment-newline-in-c

Comment: @HRgiger +1 for `System` constant.